# How to use MySQL command inside another MySQLReader while loop in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a project list in a table in MYSQL, and each project has different tables. So in my code, first I'm getting the list of projects, and from each project I'm getting data from respective tables.

```
conn.Open()
        cmdl_readuser = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM projectlist where status = 'Active'", conn)
        rl_readuser = cmdl_readuser.ExecuteReader()

        While rl_readuser.Read()
            Projectname = rl_readuser.GetString("ProjectName")
            Space_Remove(Projectname) 
            cmd_listview = New MySqlCommand("SELECT `Process`,AVG(`Risk Factor`) as AvgRisk ,AVG(`Risk Factor After Mitigation`) as AvgRiskafterImp FROM " + sTableName + "  ;", conn)
            r2_readuser = cmd_listview.ExecuteReader()
            While r2_readuser.Read()
                ProjectRiskGridView.Rows.Add(r2_readuser("Process").ToString(), r2_readuser("AvgRisk"), r2_readuser("AvgRiskafterImp"))
            End While

        End While
        conn.Close()
```

I'm getting data from table and put it in DataGridView. Finally, my DataGridView has records as list of Projects, and its respective average risk.
Here when control comes to the second MySQLCommand, it returns back. It doesn't go to next line. I think problem is with 'conn' .

Comment: I suspect that you have a terrible, terrible database schema.  Do you have a bunch of tables - one per project - all with the same schema?

Comment: WHen user add new projects, then table for that particular project created.Each projects have different data. For a report analysis, im taking average value of certain colums for each project.

Comment: Yeah, that is a terrible, terrible schema. That's not how relational databases work. If you find yourself adding tables, you're doing it wrong. You should only be adding rows. You should have a Project table and you add one row to that for each project. All your other project tables should be a single table with a foreign key to that one Project table. When you add a new project, you add a new row to the Project table, not a new table. You use the foreign key to get all the other data related to that project.

Comment: Where is the variable `sTableName` defined? And where is it set?

Comment: sTableName get value in the function Space_Remove(ProjectName)